# Why is my ngbDropdown not working in Angular 10?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap in my project for styling. When I am using ngbDropdown, the Dropdownlist is always shown below the actual dropdown item:

[image]

This is the HTML I am using:

```html
<div ngbDropdown class="d-block" id="tedder-select">
    <button class="btn btn-primary w-100" id="dropdown-tedder" (click)="scrollToTedder()"
        ngbDropdownToggle>{{selectedTedder}}</button>
    <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdown-tedder">
        <button ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let tedder of tedders"
            (click)="selectTedder(tedder)">{{tedder}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In index.html I am adding the following scripts/css:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My Dependencies in package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^10.1.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.11.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.3",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^10.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "~0.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.3"
  }
```

Thank's for your help!